# Difference between returning Future.failed(Exception) and throwing an Exception

Tags: scala

In Scala, what's the difference between returning `Future.failed(new Exception("message!"))` and `throw new Exception("message!")`?

Let's say this is happening in a function that is to return `Future[Unit]`, and the calling function is like so:

```
someFunction onFailure {
  case ex: Exception => log("Some exception was thrown")
}
```

Is there a preference of one over the other or a specific use case for each?

Answer (score 21):

Calling `Future { throw ex }` and `Future.failed(ex)` will create an equivalent result.  However, using `Future.failed` is more efficient.  If we look at this snippet from `Future.apply` (from [here in the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Future.scala)):

```
promise complete {
    try Success(body) catch { case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e) }
}
```

We notice that (as could be expected), this relies on a `try...catch` block.  These are known to carry heavy overhead when compared to normal code.  The `Future.failed` method is essentially a shortcut to this without having to incur the cost of actually ever throwing the exception.

Comment: Actually most of the overhead in exception handling comes from the instantiation of the exceptions (because they -- by default -- capture the stack, which is pretty expensive). Because you're going to instantiate the exception either way (whether you use `Future.failed` or `Future { throw ex }`), that part does not enter the equation. Which only leaves the actual throw/catch mechanism to consider. It certainly has a cost, but it is dominated by the cost of creating the exception in the first place, so using either style won't matter that much in practice.

Comment: To give you an idea, I made a (totally unscientific) benchmark to compare the execution time of the "new exception + throw + catch" case against the "new exception" case, and the difference was less than 1% on my machine.

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder if other factors like memory usage exhibit a difference as well.  Regardless, I would say that the `failed` method is cleaner and more idiomatic.

Comment: Actually let me correct myself here. There **is** a significant performance hit from using `Future { throw ex }` over `Future.failed(ex)`, altough (as I said) it has little to do with exception handling in itself. The culprit is actually that `Future.apply` executes on an `ExecutionContext` (while `Future.failed` returns a completed `Future` directly), and as such this incurs a significant additional latency (the `Future` will be executed at some point in the future, plus there is the impact of context switching). So yes, `Future.failed(ex)` is noticeably more performant.